# Identify MVC request in Global.asax.cs in Asp .NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, outputcache

Is is possible in EndRequest handler in Global.asax.cs in Asp .NET MVC 2 to idenfity whether current request handled by a mvc controller rather than a request to fetch some resource file (js, css, an image)? What further interests me, is it possible to do so even when response was once generated using a controller but is not served from OutputCache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can run this code: `this.Context.Handler is MvcHandler` in the Application_EndRequest in the Global.asax.

If you want to iterate yourself over the Routes you can do something like this:

```
if(this.Context.Handler == null)
{
            foreach (var route in RouteTable.Routes)
            {
                var foundRoute = route.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(Context));
                if(foundRoute==null)
                    continue;    

                if(foundRoute.RouteHandler is MvcRouteHandler)
                {
                  // code
                  break;
                }
            }
}
```

if I remember correctly foundRoute will be NULL if it does not match the context, but you should run this code and test it.

FYI Ignored routes implement StopRouteHandler. MvcRoutees implement MvcRouteHandler. There are some other handlers such as PageRouteHandler and ResourceRouteHandler.

Update:

BTW, I would add a hash or some caching method, if you plan to use this search, so you don't iterate over the routes every time.

Comment: Problem is that this.Context.Handler is null when content is served from OutputCache. I need a solution to work also with OutputCache.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know this... I'll look around a bit.

Comment: BTW If you haven't disabled the MVC X-AspNetMvc-Version header you can also use that, as headers are also cached. Just use the  Response.Headers.Get("X-AspNetMvc-Version") EndRequest... I'm still looking for a better solution...

Comment: can you maybe try and match the current url to a route and determine if a controller would have been found?